# Oracle Stored procedure returns error no record found to c# even when there is a record

Tags: c#, oracle

I am calling a oracle Stored procedure from my C# code with an parameter. I am sending the parameter value cuatid from a text box and The data type of the Param in oracle is number. The cust ID is present in the db.. but here I am getting cust id not found error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_cust (
    pcustid NUMBER
) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS

    pcustname    VARCHAR2(100);
    psales_ytd   NUMBER;
    pstatus      VARCHAR2(10);
    output       VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    SELECT
        custname,
        status,
        sales_ytd
    INTO
        pcustname,
        pstatus,
        psales_ytd
    FROM
        customer
    WHERE
        custid = pcustid;

    output := 'Custid:'
              || pcustid
              || ' Name:'
              || pcustname
              || ' Status:'
              || pstatus
              || ' SalesYTD:'
              || psales_ytd;

    RETURN output;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
        raise_application_error(-20002, 'Customer ID not found');
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        raise_application_error(-20000, sqlerrm);
END;
```

/

```
var connection = new OracleConnection(ConString);
                connection.Open();
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                cmd.CommandText = "get_cust";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pcustid", OracleDbType.Double).Value = EnterCustID.Text;
                 cmd.Parameters.Add("output", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               var result = cmd.Parameters["output"].Value.ToString();
                DisplayData.Items.Add(result);
                connection.Close();
```

**SOLVED**

I just interchanged the order of the lines as below and it worked

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("output", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
cmd.Parameters.Add("pcustid", OracleDbType.Double).Value = EnterCustID.Text;
```

Comment: i realize you  are a newbie .  but this question does not have enough details to help you.  please post code.....oracle procedure........your client c# code.

Comment: At least post the entire text of the error message you are getting.

Comment: @granadaCoder sorry I was trying post from my mobile and it got messed up.. now I updated the details

Comment: Have you tried adding the `pcustid` value to the error message?  Either the customer ID you're passing in isn't the customer ID you think you're passing in or the customer ID actually doesn't exist (at least within the scope of the procedure call).

Comment: "pcustid" may be u have field in table customer with same name?

Comment: @JustinCave. I tried adding the pcustid to the error message and it is empty. i tried Printing the Textbox.text in the C# and i am seeing the value. Also i tried executing the function get_cust(10) is Oracle sql developer and i am getting the record details.Only from the C# i am not getting